Black flickering in C XLib on resize
I wrote a program that renders to XLib window in 60fps.
When i resize the window, XLib seems to clear the window to black and the effect lingers before it is time for my 60fps render cycle to repaint it, leading to annoying flickers on window resize.
The best i seem to be able to do to mitigate this is to basically repaint the screen every time it is resized, which removes most of the flickering, but not all of it. Isn't there some sort of thing i can do to eliminate the flickering completely? Ideally, i'd love some way to tell the Xlib to simply not clear the window to black on resize.
Here is the code for my ConfigureNotify event handler that i use to handle window resizing:
    case ConfigureNotify:
    if (ev.xconfigure.width != ximg.width 
        || ev.xconfigure.height != ximg.height) {
        ximg.width = ev.xconfigure.width;
        ximg.height = ev.xconfigure.height;
        RenderResize(ximg.width, ximg.height);
        ximg.bytes_per_line = RenderGetBytesPerRow();
        ximg.data = RenderGetMemory();
        PlatformPasteBuffer(displayPt, window, gc, &ximg);
    }

RenderResize is function that resizes the internal memory buffer, which is subsequently assigned to XImage data. PlatformPasteBuffer copies XImage over to the window.
Here is the way i instantiate the window to begin with:
    displayPt = XOpenDisplay(NULL);
    s32 screenId = DefaultScreen(displayPt);
    ximg = *XCreateImage(displayPt, DefaultVisual(displayPt, screenId),
        DefaultDepth(displayPt, screenId), ZPixmap, 0, RenderGetMemory(),
        pxWidth, pxHeight, bpp * 8, RenderGetBytesPerRow());

    u64 rootWindow = XRootWindow(displayPt, screenId);
    window = XCreateSimpleWindow(displayPt, rootWindow,
        0, 0, ximg.width, ximg.height, 0, 0, 0);
    gc = XCreateGC(displayPt, window, 0, 0);

I expected that manually repainting the window when handling ConfigureNotify will completely eliminate the problem in all cases. However, it seems to work more like a crutch and not a direct solution to the problem.

You need double buffering for smooth window resizing. Unfortunately, my X11 days are long gone, so I cannot serve with details.
